# Listing data inside a JSON object

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, output

I am trying to extract data from an API with python.
With this code, I am trying to print the content of dictionaries within a list.

```
response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = response.json()
log = json.dumps(data['result'], indent = 1)
print log
```

So far so good, it prints:

```
[
{
"line": "something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
}, 
{
"line": "something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
}, 
{
"line": "something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
}, 
]
```

Is there a way for the output to look like below?

```
"something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
"something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
"something@gmail.com:birthdaydate"
```

Comment: I'm sorry you received down votes which I attribute simply to your confusion about how the json library works. In my view, for a 'New contributor', you have largely fulfilled the requirements of question writing on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = response.json()
log = data['result']
for l in log:
    print(l["line"])
```

Comment: if it helped you, please accept the answer in order to help other developers who struggling with same issue.